# OpenGL 3 plain text man pages

Tags: opengl

For the last hour or so I have been trying to download plain text OpenGL 3.3 man pages, but to no avail. I am trying to read and understand others' OpenGL code, and having local, plain text man pages which can be read from the terminal would be a great timesaver for me.

The only source I found for OpenGL 3 man pages was from https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/. The content is fine, but having to frequently switch back-and-forth to the browser and use the mouse has become a frustrating time sink for me. I noticed that the links to the man pages in the left bar were all links to xml pages. So far, I have tried downloading the xml man pages from their website using wget and converting them into plain text, but their webpage has so far defeated most of my attempts in the past hour at even downloading their xml manpages. (Some requests yield the needed xml document, but most result in a generic xml "out of date browser" error message or redirect page).

Of course, at this point I have probably spent more time on this problem than I could hope to save by solving it, but I'm still intent on solving it. Any pointers for converting to or locating text manpages would be appreciated, and be very helpful to me.

Comment: FYI: The 3.3 pages are *woefully* out of date. That is, they actually have incorrect information, and the ARB has steadfastly *refused* to correct them. Even if you're only restricted to using 3.3, you should use the 4.5 pages; those at least get bugfixes.

Comment: @NicolBolas You're a saviour!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [OpenGL Wiki has an article](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_started/XML_Toolchain_and_Man_Pages) that explains the general conversion steps.

To download the pages, you have to use SVN (Yes, SVN in 2015. Despite the fact that Khronos clearly has [heard of and uses Git](https://github.com/KhronosGroup)). The SVN repo for 3.3 is here: https://cvs.khronos.org/svn/repos/ogl/trunk/ecosystem/public/sdk/docs/man3/; you can use public, anonymous access to pull from the reop. Though I do suggest that you use `man4` to get the 4.5 pages, as those have many bug fixes the 3.3 pages don't get. And the 3.3 pages will never see any bug fixes.

From there, you can use them however you wish. The pages are DocBook XML (kinda), so you could read them as-is. But you could use the DocBook XSL stylesheets, as suggested in the wiki article, to convert them into Unix manpages or HTML or even a PDF file.

Comment: In addition to that I also strongly recommend to consult the actual specification if you're uncertain about the details of a function.